# How to use norm.ppf and xlim() in a for loop (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy, normal-distribution

I have a for loop I am using to plot multiple figures of the Normal distribution.
In this loop, when i use use the respective data as an argument to plot e.g.
`plt.plot(data1, fitted_pdf, 'K', linewidth=2)`, i get a rough normal curve.

I want a smoother curve but when I try using xmin,xmax=plt.xlim for the first argument in plt.plot, i dont get a normal distribution.

However, if I remove all but one data set and use xlim(), I get a very smooth curve that looks much better than when i use the data as argument.

This also relates to another issue in the for loop. I also want to calculate the cumulative distribution function and its inverse using norm.cdf and norm.ppf respectively but when I write this into the for loop, it gives me only one value. Putting arugments, that is, the mean and standard deviation for norm.cdf and norm.ppf gives me wrong numbers.

Can someone please look at this snippet of my code and tell me whats wrong.
Thanks

```
totalIPs=[[1,3,6,8,44,5],[33,55,66,77,98],[445,65,67,33,55],[33,44,55,77,88]]

for item in totalIPs:

        mu=statistics.mean(item)
        std=statistics.stdev(item)

        xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
        x=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)

        fitted_pdf=ss.norm.pdf(x,mu, std)

        plt.figure()

        plt.xlabel('Distribution of patents by IP firms',fontsize=12)

        plt.ylabel('Frequency of firms of each patents',fontsize=12)

        plt.hist(x, bins=10,normed=True, alpha=0.6, edgecolor='black', color = 'g')

        plt.plot(x, fitted_pdf, 'K', linewidth=2)
            title = "Japan IP firms patent filings: mu =%.2f, std = %.2f"%(mu,std)
        plt.title(title)

        proportion=1-ss.norm.cdf(0.5)
        threshold=norm.ppf(1-0.44)

        print(proportion)
        print(threshold)
```

I think for xlim() its trying to set one x limit for all my graphs but by putting it inside the for loop it should know to use different data points from index position 0 to n to set the x limits

Comment: You call `plt.xlim` before creating a figure. So what are you expecting it to return? In subsequent loop steps it will take the limits of the previous figure, which is undesired as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I dont want it to take the limits of the previous figure. I want it to plot individual limits for all the figures like how a for construct does when applied to a list. E.g. List =[1,2,3,4,5,6]. For x in list: Print (x). Returns 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Yes, so don't use `xlim` before creating the figure. And since for the figure you already need some `x`, don't use `xlim` at all.

Comment: That's good advice but how else can I get a suer smooth curve. The difference between using xlim() and using the data as arguments is night and day. How do all these research papers plot so many graphs of a range of data and still end up with high quality plots. If you know another way that I could use to get a smooth normal distribution please let me know.